# Location of PolicyKit log output

Tags: logging, policykit

I'm trying to debug a new PolicyKit rule that looks like this:

```js
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    polkit.log("action=" + action);
    polkit.log("subject=" + subject);
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-unmount-others"){
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

But I can't find the output of the `polkit.log()` calls anywhere in `/var/log/`. I even tried adding a line to `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

```
*.*         /var/log/all
```

which produces lots of output, but not for `polkit.log()`. Where can I find the log messages for these calls?

Answer (score 3):

From the [policykit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) documentation:

> The `log()` method writes the given message to the system logger
>   prefixed with the JavaScript filename and line number. Log entries are
>   emitted using the `LOG_AUTHPRIV` flag meaning that the log entries
>   usually ends up in the file `/var/log/secure`. The `log()` method is
>   usually only used when debugging rules. The Action and Subject types
>   has suitable `toString()` methods defined for easy logging, for
>   example,
>
> ```
> polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
>     if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.policykit.exec") {
>         polkit.log("action=" + action);
>         polkit.log("subject=" + subject);
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> will produce the following when the user runs `pkexec -u bateman bash -i` from a shell:
>
> ```
> May 24 14:28:50 thinkpad polkitd[32217]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-test.rules:3: action=[Action id='org.freedesktop.policykit.exec' command_line='/usr/bin/bash -i' program='/usr/bin/bash' user='bateman' user.gecos='Patrick Bateman' user.display='Patrick Bateman (bateman)']
> May 24 14:28:50 thinkpad polkitd[32217]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-test.rules:4: subject=[Subject pid=1352 user='davidz' groups=davidz,wheel, seat='seat0' session='1' local=true active=true]
> ```

This type of log events is usually found in `/var/log/auth.log` in Debian and its derivatives including Ubuntu.

Source: [/var/log/secure not present in 14.04 ,is there any alternative?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534324/var-log-secure-not-present-in-14-04-is-there-any-alternative)

Comment: I've tried that example, and can't get it to work. Also tested on  a fresh Ubuntu VM. As far as I can tell, my `.rules` file is never being executed.


Futhermore, the last entry I have in `/var/log/auth.log` is over two years old, which seems rather strange...

Comment: @Keidax, it's another problem. But logs should be `/var/log/auth.log`. May I suggest to open a new question for your rules file never executed?

Comment: Alright, posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/536591/45425).

Comment: This will not work. As of now (Ubuntu 19.04) and for the foreseeable future (19.10 betas), Ubuntu uses polkit 0.105.  The javascript/ECMAscript rules were enabled on version 0.106. https://askubuntu.com/a/704062/10542