# PolicyKit rules never come into effect

Tags: policykit

I'm trying to write a new `.rules` file for PolicyKit. My test attempt (in the directory `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/`) looks like this:

```js
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    polkit.spawn(["rm","/home/gabriel/test"]);
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.policykit.exec") {
        polkit.log("action=" + action);
        polkit.log("subject=" + subject);
    }
    return polkit.Result.NOT_HANDLED;
});
```

But as far as I can tell, this code is never run. The `test` file is still there, and there's no log output after running something like `$ pkexec -u otheruser bash`

(I have tried marking the `.rules` files as executable.)

Answer (score 26):

If you are on [Ubuntu 22.04 (or lower)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpolkit) then you are still using the old version of PolKit, where there are no .rules files but only .pkla and .conf files.

On the command prompt, do:

```
pkaction --version
```

If it says < 0.106, then you can only use the old syntax.

You can create a .pkla file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/`, see `man pklocalauthority` for directions and examples.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 is still on the old version.  ````pkaction --version```` gives ````pkaction version 0.105````

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 still carries 0.105!!!! Oh, my!!!!

Comment: And even no 0.106+ version is in repos for Ubuntu! OMG!

Comment: ubuntu 19.04 `pkaction version 0.105`. New rules files are written in JavaScript unsupported.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 still uses 0.105

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 still uses 0.105!!!! I can't believe ubuntu is using an 8-year-old version of polkit.

Comment: What if I have a `.rules` file like in the question? I simply change its extension and move it to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/`?

Comment: [This has some of the reasoning behind refusing to upgrade](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=946231#10) it.. (Ubuntu is debian with a few extra things added)

Comment: A newer version was [merged into Debian unstable (sid) in October 2022](https://packages.debian.org/sid/policykit-1) (which forms the basis for Ubuntu, so a newer version might be available in 23.04 and the next LTS (likely 24.04) `121+compat0.1-5` was the first newer version to get out of experimental

Answer (score 0):

To work as expected, you have to put your own `.rules` files in:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
```

Note that it should also solve this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536405/location-of-policykit-log-output).

Comment: Moving the file there didn't seem to change anything. Also, according to [the polkit docs](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) and [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PolicyKit), `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` should be used for user configuration. So I'm not sure what difference changing directories makes.

Comment: @Keidax: what's the name of your `.rules` file?

Comment: Currently `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/10-udisks-personal.rules`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (ubuntu 22.04 with pkaction version 0.105):

Edit the following file:

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

And make the first section look like:

```
[Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat;
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Reboot is not required. Works just after you edit the file.

Note I added "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat" here.
In my case, when I was trying to mount a disk from commandline, I was receiving the following message:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat ===
Authentication is required to mount WD Elements 25A3 (/dev/sdb1)
Authenticating as: User,,, (user)
```