# How do I allow a group to manage a systemd service using polkit?

Tags: permissions, services, policykit

I have a service (`some-service`) on my system that I'd like to allow members of group `managers` to control (start, stop, restart). I would also allow these users to use PolicyKit instead of `sudo` for various reasons.

However, Ubuntu 16.04 does not (yet) have PolicyKit version 0.106, meaning the rules system present in that version does not exist, meaning I need to use PKLA files [as documented here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536591/policykit-rules-never-come-into-effect).

How would I write these rules on PolicyKit 0.105 and only allow `managers` to only control `some-service`?