# Allow systemd service to be started or stopped by non sudo user

Tags: permissions, systemd

I have a minecraft server setup on my home server, and I want to allow any of my friends to be able to ssh in and start the server themselves.  However, I don't necessarily want to give them sudo access.

Is there a way I can mark a particular service as being able to be started or stopped by anyone, or by members of a particular group?

Comment: At the moment, not a particular service (see related http://askubuntu.com/q/875522/158442 for the problem). It's all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely. While `sudo` is associated with running any command as `root`, it's a really a flexible system that allows fine-grained control of who has access to run what specific commands.

For example, you can create a group called `minecraftstarters` and add all your friends to it. Then you can a define a `sudo` rule which allows anyone in the `minecraftstarters` group to start or restart Minecraft, but not be able to use `sudo` for anything else.

Then in `/etc/sudoers.d/minecraft`, you would add syntax like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias MINECRAFT_CMDS = /bin/systemctl start minecraft, /bin/systemctl restart minecraft
%minecraftstarters ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: MINECRAFT_CMDS
```

Now you've defined some commands that the `minecraftstarters` group can run with `sudo` (and without requiring an additional password prompt).

Tip: Use `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/minecraft` to edit the file. It will check the syntax before it saves it, avoiding the unfortunate state where you break your `sudo` configuration, so `sudo` doesn't work at all.