# How can I mount partitions in Thunar without password?

Tags: mount, policykit

I've tried adding the following to my `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`

```
[storage group mount override]  
Identity=unix-user:ada  
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system  
ResultsAny=yes  
ResultsInactive=yes  
ResultsActive=yes
```

As far as I can remember, it worked in Ubuntu 17.10. Now, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04(mini.iso) + i3wm without any Display Manager.
Update 1:
Tried adding the following lines to `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-udisks2.rules`

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {  
if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system" ||  
action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount") &&  
subject.isInGroup("sudo")) {  
return polkit.Result.YES;  
}  
});
```

still getting the password prompt when mounting drives in Thunar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could edit the file org.freedesktop.udisks2.policy in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions.
Search for the textblock containing the line:
`<action id="org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system">`
At the bottom of this block you will find the line:
`<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>`
Change `auth_admin_keep` to `yes` and you will be able to mout partitions without being asked for a password. However any user wil be able to perform this action.

The .rules files will not work since the polkit version installed in 18.04 is 0.105, .rules files can only be used in version 0.106 and higher. I don't know why your solution isn't working, it seems to be conforming to polkit rules. See the following answer as well: [PolicyKit rules never come into effect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536591/policykit-rules-never-come-into-effect) .

Comment: It worked. "Other users might be able to mount without auth" won't be a problem to me though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may find an answer [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1192269/mounting-partitions-without-a-password-using-udisks2)

Seems you need to create file /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-udisks2.rules

Comment: okay . I'll try that. But can you plz explain Why my method failed?

Comment: I tried that. It's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit your question with details of what you tried.